# iOS background usage of Network.Framework

Tags: ios, background-process, network.framework

I've written a simple WiFi based App using TCP on Network.Framework that receives about 80 bytes every 10s from a remote service on specific port. I want to write this data to file while in the foreground and the background.

The question is which of the [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) if any/is permitted/best fits this requirement?

All wisdom gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else about your app (is it a music app?, location?, VoIP?, bluetooth?) it's hard to say what you might do. But there are two classes of background actions:

1. Actions that are ongoing when you go to the background that can be finished.
2. Permitted background actions for specific kinds of apps. See "Implementing Long-Running Tasks" in the link you have about background modes.

The first doesn't really apply to you since this is ongoing. Of the second items, I'd guess that "Background fetch" is the one that fits best.

Note that you won't necessarily be called as regularly as you might like. But since your time interval is quite long (10sec) then a few hundred milliseconds latency wouldn't be particularly damaging I'd guess.

But also note that "Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches. The system must balance your app’s need to fetch content with the needs of other apps and the system itself."

Comment: Background fetch won’t work. That only happens every 3 or 4 hours at most. If you don’t want to go into the App Store you can “abuse” background audio play playing “silence”. If you want App Store approval then I don’t think that there is a suitable solution

Comment: The first issue is to prevent disconnection on entry into the background. network.framework enters the cancelled state (connection closed) on entry into background.

Comment: I am facing issue when device1 application goes on background mode and device2 application from foreground mode try to send information and device1 not able to receive it , any help on this?